# Parse excel file in java

Tags: java, excel, java-8, hashmap

I have an excel file that contains in it Map<Integer,String>
In the excel I have for example:

| FirstName | LastName | Sports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FirstName1 | LastName1 | [{1:"Football"},{2:"Handball"}] |
| FirstName2 | LastName2 | [{1:"Hockey"},{2:"Archery"},{3:"Karate"}] |
| FirstName3 | LastName3 | [{1:"Karate"},{2:"Boxing"},{3:"Baseball"},{4:"Running"}] |

I need to get the values of the map, for example for the first one to get Football,Handball as List, and same for the second one and so go on.
Please help me, I am using Java8
I know how to get the stringValues,numericValues,booleanValues from a cell,but for this I have a problem.

```
row.getCell(index).getStringCellValue();
row.getCell(index).getNumericCellValue();
```

Comment: what do you mean by ```List<Map<Integer,String>>```???

Comment: I mean List of Maps that have Integer key and String value, I have exmple above of the excel that needs to be parsed.

Comment: I think he means that every row is a name, a surname and then the serialization of a dictionary int->string

but putting a snippet of the data table would be a good idea.
as the "excel" part is not that important, since he knows how to read data

A map for every line is not a list of map

Comment: Oh yes you are right, i will change in my question

Comment: So ```FirstName``` , ```LastName``` and ```Sports``` are seperate columns and each row has 3 column data ?

Comment: Yes, the 3 column is Map, but I thnik that is clear from the example, i know how to get firstName and LastName columns, with getStringValue(), but the problem is with the 3 column that contains Map

Comment: you will always get the input in 3rd column in the following format ? ```[{1:"Football"},{2:"Handball"}]``` ??

Comment: yes, that's the input

Answer (score 0):

You have a write a few lines of code to convert the 3rd column to your desired format .

you have to get the 3rd column as `String` ., like `String mapColumn=row.getCell(index).getStringCellValue();`

Then you have to iterate the String as JSONArray (From org.json). I have written a stub .This might give you an idea .

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        
        String s="[{1:\"Football\"},{2:\"Handball\"}]";// Your 3rd Column Value
        JSONArray js=new JSONArray(s);              // Converting the String to JSONArray
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();  //Creating a list
        for(int i=0;i<js.length();i++) {
            list.add(js.getJSONObject(i).getString(String.valueOf(i+1)));  //adding values to list
        }
        
        System.out.println(list.toString());   // Gives your desired output
    }
```

Sample output :
`[Football, Handball]`